# Chrome custom tab stopping when opening deeplink through it

Tags: android, branch.io, chrome-custom-tabs

When I launch a deep-link(which directs to within app activity) inside chrome custom tabs,than app gets closed. Not able to figure out any reason yet. I am using Branch.io for deeplinking.

Expected behavior is to open the activity which is redirected from link.

For More Detail:

- Inside my application,there is Activity A, I clicked on a link inside
  Activity A
- Than that link opens in Chrome CustomTabs by calling launchUrl() from
  Activity A
- Now That link which was clicked from Activity A is actually a Deep
  Link, of which browser behavior was, it open my Application Activity
  B from my browser
- But when this link opens CustomChromeTab My application Closes,
  without going to Activity B as desired
- Lastly I cannot see any error in logcat

Comment: Can you please provide more details in your question? It seems that you are clicking on a link when navigating inside a Custom Tab, and the expected behaviour is for an app activity to be started, but something is going wrong. Is the link to a different application than the one that hosts the Custom Tab? Is it the Custom Tab activity that is getting closed when the link is clicked, the host app or the app that is being deep-linked? Can you see any errors on logcat when the application is closed?

Comment: @andreban Yup thanks for commenting, following are the details will help you understand my situation:
>Inside my application,there is Activity A, I clicked on a link inside Activity A
>Than that link opens in Chrome CustomTabs by calling launchUrl() from Activity A
> Now That link which was clicked from Activity A is actually a Deep Link, of which browser behavior was, it open my Application Activity B from my browser
>But when this link opens CustomChromeTab My application Closes, without going to Activity B as desired.> Lastly I cannot see any error in logcat

Comment: Thanks for the details. I'd recommend updating the original question with those details to help other people reading the question without having to go through the comments. Regarding the deeplink, does it use an http/https schema or does it use a custom schema?

Comment: @andreban Updated! Not really. Just a branch deep link which directs to a browser to open my App Activity B and from Activity B, I fetch respective JSON to take further actions. But the issue is I am not able to open Activity B since after chrome tabs open and then closes the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** this actually might be due to a bug we had in a recent version of the Branch SDK on Android. Could you confirm you're using v2.4.4 or higher?

Alex from Branch.io here: glad to hear you're finding Branch links useful! Branch doesn't actually support within-the-app deep linking, which sounds like what you're trying to implement. You'd be better off using standard mechanisms for moving between activities within the app, and rely on Branch to handle users coming from outside of it.

Comment: Glad for your reply, I am using **Branch SDK Android v2.3.0**. And I agree that branch will handle users coming from outside of the application, therefore I am using ChromeTabs(working as a browser) to open all links in which branch links are the subset. So for links other than branch are working fine inside chrome custom tabs, but only the branch link are closing the application, inplace of previous behavior on Chrome browser or any other browser was to open desired Activity of App.

Comment: Ahhh. See if updating to the latest SDK helps. If not, we can go from there 

Comment: I have updated the library from v2.3.0 to 2.4.4, still, the issue continues. Apparently, I have solved my issue by deep digging into Branch.java code flow, and have got that previously initialized session was every time been used in place of new session. I solved my problem by two steps. So Firstly by opeining Activity B (as said above) from handling link click and handling it own without letting it run in browser or chromeTabs and secondly using **branch.resetUserSession();** before initSession() method solved my problem and everything is now working fine.

Comment: Glad to hear you got sorted out! Thanks for the update